# Simplify a list where every element is itself a list of maps using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

After parsing my JSON file with JSON Parser, I get the following list in Java:

```java
List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> fields  = jsonContext.read(jsonPath);
```

Every element in this list is itself a list of `HashMap`s and results from the following JSON structure:

```json
[
  {
   "value": "such",
   "name": "yname"
  },
  {
    "value": "Suchwort",
    "name": "yvbeds"
  },
  {
    "value": "",
    "name": "yfix"
  },
  {
    "value": "such",
    "name": "yzielfeld"
   }
],
[
  {
   "value": "ftext",
   "name": "yname"
  },
  {
   "value": "Freitext 1",
   "name": "yvbeds"
  },
  {
    "value": "",
    "name": "yfix"
  },
  {
    "value": "ftext",
    "name": "yzielfeld"
  }
],
```

This JSON structure creates four maps, each having two key/value pairs. I would like to convert these four maps into a single map. I have achieved this without using streams as follows:

```java
List<HashMap<String,String>> newList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0;i< fields.size();i++) {
    HashMap<String,String> singleMap = new HashMap<>();
    List<HashMap<String,String>> listItem = fields.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<listItem.size();j++) {
        HashMap<String,String> fieldMap = listItem.get(j);
        singleMap.put(fieldMap.get("name"),fieldMap.get("value"));
    }
    newList.add(singleMap);

}
```

I have tried the following stream approach but after collecting to map, I need to collect to `List` again but there are only map options:

```java
List<HashMap<String,String>> newList = fields.stream()
   .flatMap(List::stream)
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(value->value.get("name"),value->value.get("value")))
   .
```

How can I implement this using streams?

Comment: You should provide the expected and actual outputs for your example and clarify what do you mean by "without success". Just saying that is not useful.

Comment: I have mentioned that I have achieved the desired output but without using streams. I want the same output with streams.

Comment: actually this: "This json structure creates four maps, each having two key value pairs.", should be: "this json structure results in a List containing two inner lists. Each inner list has four HashMaps, and each HashMap contains two key-value pairs: `name` and `value`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your non-stream code, you seem to want to map each *inner list* into its own separate `Map`.

Therefore, you should not flatten (`flatMap`) the outer list. `map` the outer list, and `collect(toMap)` each inner list.

```
List<Map<String, String>> result = fields.stream()
    .map(
        l -> l.stream().collect(
            // assuming the maps in each inner list do not have duplicate names
            Collectors.toMap(x -> x.get("name"), x -> x.get("value"))
            // if they do, give an appropriate merger function as the 3rd argument
        )
    )
    .toList();
```

Comment: Your answer works, just needed conversion to List via collect method which I have corrected

Comment: @user1107888 That is a Java 16 API. If you are using a lower version then, yeah, you should use `collect` instead.